# Validating elements of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, validation, for-loop, multidimensional-array

My code for making sure an element isn't over 100 or less than 0 is:

```java
boolean test = true;
for (int i = 0; i < inArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < inArray[0].length; j++) {
        if (inArray[i][j] <= 1 && inArray[i][j] >= 100) {
            test = false;
        }
    }
}
return test;
```

Except no matter what the input is the answer is always `true`

My input `array` is

```
{12, 1331, 23, 5, 1, 3},
{22, 23, 231, 21312, 1, 3},
{23, 31, 343, 3432, 1, 3},
{42, 12, 5454, 1212, 3, 9}
```

test should = false if I input this no?

College rules mean I cannot use `break;` or `return` anywhere other than the end of the sub module.

Comment: One thing to note: look at your inner for loop. Which array are you iterating over, vs. which array are you testing the length for? And then look at your `if` statement. Closely. What does `&&` mean?

Comment: Since I am testing the bounds for min > 1 and max < 100, wouldn't the best way to test for the opposite bounds to ensure it doesn't loop for a inbounds value? That was my logic anyway

Comment: @DaffyFarm That's not what you are testing. You are testing the opposite.

Comment: When you test for `(a && b)` you are testing for both a and b being true _at the same time_, and there is no integer number that is both lower than 2 and higher than 99 at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems here, two of which are critical. First, if you want to iterate over each subarray, test *its* length, not the length of array[0] every time. And second, integers cannot be less than 2 *and* over 99, so your conditional `(inArray[i][j] <= 1 &&  inArray[i][j] >= 100)` is never going to fire.

However, there's more at play here: if your test is purely to see whether your 2d array is valid, don't do more work than necessary. You can literally stop once you find a single bad element. Now, we *could* do that by adding a check to your `for` conditionals. E.g. we can rename your variable to `valid` (because you should name variables after what they represent), and then we can update your outer loop to `for(int i=0; valid && i < arr.length; i++) { ... }` with the corresponding `valid && ...` in the inner loop, too, but we're not going to. This code "does a thing" (namely it "tests for element validity" for any array-of-arrays), and code that "does a thing" should be in its own method, with a method name that describes what it does. And this makes "not doing any of the work we don't need to do" much, much easier: we just exit the function when we know we've done enough work to produce an answer.

So let's do that:

```java
// 1st fix: this code "does soemthing". Do that as a method.
public boolean testForValidContent(int[][] arr) {
  // We don't need a variable to track things: because we're
  // returning a value, we can simply return the right value
  // at the moment we return.

  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) { // 2nd fix: check the right array's length
      if(arri][j] <= 1 || arr[i][j] >= 100) { // 3th fix: OR, not AND

        // At this point we know the array is not valid, so there
        // is no point in running even a single thing more:
        return false;

      }
    }
  }

  // We checked the entire array, and everything's valid:
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer

Comment: I've updated the code a bit because you deserve to see what this should look like in real code folks write.

Answer (score 1):

Update your for loop condition to `i < inArray.length && test` and `j < inArray[0].length && test` which would force your loop to end once an invalid nos is found
and your if condition to `inArray[i][j] <= 1 ||  inArray[i][j] >= 100`

```
boolean test = true

        for(int i = 0; i < inArray.length && test; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < inArray[0].length && test; j++){ 
                if(inArray[i][j] <= 1 ||  inArray[i][j] >= 100){    
                    test = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return test;
```

you can also skip a `if` block by,

```
boolean test = true

        for(int i = 0; i < inArray.length && test; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < inArray[0].length && test; j++){ 
                test = (1 < inArray[i][j]  && inArray[i][j] < 100)  
            }
        }

        return test;
```

Comment: I just tested this and I still get True no matter what input I put in

Comment: which condition is impossible `inArray[i][j] <= 1 ||  inArray[i][j] >= 100` or `inArray[i][j] <= 1 ||  inArray[i][j] >= 100` ? @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: test will always keep setting until it is false . So whats wrong with the code ? Have you even try executing it ? @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: ah, you added the `&& test`... but why is your code still testing against `inArray[0]`? This is Java, not Mathematica: 2d arrays are arrays-of-arrays, every subarray can have a different length.